# Creating Grafana Variables with MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, grafana, grafana-variable

I have some problems with mongodb query..

I will give an example with sql query and I want to write that with mongo db query in Grafana. Grafana supports mongo db 'find'  and 'aggregate'.

table name = flow , column name = level

**sql query example 1**;

select distinc level from flow

**mongo db query: ?**

**sql query example 2** ;

select * from flow
where level = 'error'

**mongo db query:** ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: Yes I used custom variables on Grafana. I didn't use query